# How do I display 4 columns of data in one UITableView using 4 different labels for each cell

Tags: swift, xcode

I am currently working on an app that allows users to input data into a form and the data will be stored in coredata locally. The data will be displayed in a table view in cells by admins. There are four types of data that has to be logged into a table cell. I tried using four labels in one cell to allow the data to be printed into the cell. [Here is my table view right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8piB.jpg).

This is some of my code right now.

The first part is on how the code extracts data and assignment to the four labels.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let person = people[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Table_VC_Cell

        cell.nameLabel.text = person.value(forKey: "name") as? String
        cell.placeLabel.text = person.value(forKey: "place") as? String
        cell.contactnoLabel.text = person.value(forKey: "contactno") as? String
        cell.purposeLabel.text = person.value(forKey: "purposeofvisit") as? String
        return cell
    }


}
```

This part is the connection of the labels and the code.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var placeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactnoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var purposeLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Whenever I display the tables after inputting data in the form, the app crashes. Xcode specifically told me that the errors were due to this chunk of code. How should I go about fixing that?

Comment: please show us the error

Comment: and the line, where the error occurs...

Comment: Most likely your outlets are not connected or connected to the wrong thing, but without the stack trace for the error no-one can tell you for sure.

Comment: My apologies for not attaching the error, here's a screenshot of it. [error](https://imgur.com/laN7gBw).

Comment: Either the identifier or the (custom) class of the cell is not set properly in Interface Builder.